# How can I speed up page load times while developing a Confluence macro with the Atlassian SDK? batch.js and batch.css taking up to 50 seconds

Tags: confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I've gone through the Confluence "Hello World" tutorial (https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/create-a-confluence-hello-world-macro) and have a working macro.
But **every** page refresh takes up to 50 seconds, due to `batch.css` and `batch.js` probably being regenerated.

I've already tried a couple of suggestions given in different Atlassian forum threads.
Currently `pom.xml` looks the following

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                ...
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    ...
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <!-- make AMPS faster -->
                    <enableDevToolbox>false</enableDevToolbox>
                    <enablePde>false</enablePde>
                    ...

    <properties>
        <confluence.version>6.14.0</confluence.version>
        <confluence.data.version>6.14.0</confluence.data.version>
        <atlassian.dev.mode>false</atlassian.dev.mode>
        <amps.version>8.0.2</amps.version>
        ...
```

I've tried disabling batching with a `quickreload.properties` file in the plugin home directory with the following content

```
# non-filepath directive to quickreload to turn off batching (note the qr: prefix)
qr:webresourcebatching=false
```

But that only moves the issue to having hundreds of single files all together taking 40-50 seconds.

And I tried using `ATLAS_OPTS="-Datlassian.dev.mode=false"` as environment settings.

[Screenshot of Firefox developer tools network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94KXY.png)